# Set default value in drop down

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have two drop down that can be manipulate. The second drop down; httpauthmode is manipulated by the value in the first drop down;httprestype.

I want the second drop down; httpauthmode to change to default value when user selected 
httpreqtype() == 2; i.e

```
      <option value="0" selected="selected">None</option>
      //I want the value = 0 be the default value
```

**Javascript**

```
  _self.httpreqtype = ko.observable( httpreqtype );
  _self.httpauthmode = ko.observable(null);
```

**Here is my html**

```
  <label>HTTP Request Type</label><br/>
    <select data-bind="value: httpreqtype" style="width:200px">
    <?php 
        foreach($httpRequestOptions as $key=>$val) {
            echo '<option value="'.$val["id"].'" >'.$val["name"].'</option>';
        };
    ?>
    //$httpRequestOptions is an array inside my viewModel, I only put a piece of my code
    </select>

    <label>HTTP Auth Type</label><br />
    <select data-bind="value: httpauthmode" style="width:200px">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">None</option>
        <option value="1">Basic Authentication</option>
        <option value="2" data-bind = "visible: httpreqtype() == 2" >Body Encryption</option>
        <option value="3" data-bind = "visible: httpreqtype() == 2" >Basic Authentication + Body Encryption</option>
    </select>
```

I try hours googling and already tried subscribe function, set the observable to (null), ("") and many other ways. Can someone expert help me or maybe suggest what method I can try. Really appreciate it and many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `httpauthmode` to `'0'` (value of *`None`*) when `httprestype` changes to `'2'`:

```
_self.httprestype.subscribe(function(value) {
    if(value === '2') {
        _self.httpauthmode('0');
    }
});
```

[**`JSFiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/atpzg7xL/)

Comment: yeay, your code works! I modifying some of your code (removing the if statement) that actually give results exactly what I want. The _self.httpauthmode('0') actually did the trick because I did put it somewhere in my computed functions and it works too. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

You should approach this very differently. Carefully read the [`options` binding documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) and try to rework your code to that approach. Basically it allows you to data bind the `select` tag, and have the `option`s rendered dynamically by Knockout.

Something like this:

```js
var Model = function(httpreqtype){
  var _self = this;
  _self.httpauthmode = ko.observable(null);
  _self.httpreqtype = ko.observable( httpreqtype );
  _self.httpauthmode = ko.observable(null);
  
  var mode0 = { id: 0, txt: "None" };
  var mode1 = { id: 1, txt: "Basic Authentication" };
  var mode2 = { id: 2, txt: "Body Encryption" };
  var mode3 = { id: 3, txt: "Basic Authentication" };
    
  _self.availableHttpAuthModes = ko.computed(function() {
    if (_self.httpreqtype() == 2) {
      return [mode0, mode1];
    }
    return [mode0, mode1, mode2, mode3];
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new Model(2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="value: httpauthmode, 
                   optionsText: 'txt',
                   options: availableHttpAuthModes" >
</select>
<br /><br />Change httpreqtype:
<br /><input data-bind="value: httpreqtype, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
```

Comment: Although your code works wonderfully, I still require to manipulated between 2 drop down. But I already found out a way to make that works by modifying some of my subscribe function. Anyway, really appreciate the suggestion though. Thanks!